# If I memorialize a Facebook account for a deceased person and they had set their account not to allow posting, will I still get the tribute function?

Tags: facebook

Suppose I memorialize a Facebook account for a deceased family member, and they had set their Facebook account not to allow posting (although comments on things they put up were allowed). Will I still get the tribute function where everyone can write in? Or will that not be allowed since the deceased originally had set it to no posting function?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)